# Caret pointing down when accordion panel is open not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the little caret pointing down in my accordion when a panel is opened but I've been having problem with my jquery. Don't quite understand what I'm doing.

```
$('#accordion .panel-heading').click(function () {
    $('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
    $('.panel-heading .active').find('b').addClass('opened').removeClass('closed'); 
    $('.panel-heading').not('active').find('b').addClass('closed').removeClass('opened'); 
});
```

Any help? **[Code right here](http://www.bootply.com/0fHUqXpNn6)**.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so there were several issues with what you were doing. The selector .not('active') was not looking for the active class. But the major issue was that you didn't handle if the user clicked the same already active accordion.

The following will check to see if the current panel is active. If it is not the logic is easy, make it active, clear all open and set this one to opened.

If the active panel was clicked, check to see if it was opened, if so remove opened, if not set opened.

```
$('#accordion .panel-heading').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
      // the element clicked was not active, but now is - 
      $('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active'); 
      setIconOpened(this);
    }
    else
    {    
      // active panel was reclicked
      if ($(this).find('b').hasClass('opened'))
      {
        setIconOpened(null);
      }
      else
      {
        setIconOpened(this);
      }
    }
});

// create a function to set the open icon for the given panel
// clearing out all the rest (activePanel CAN be null if nothing is open)
function setIconOpened(activePanel) {
  $('.panel-heading').find('b').addClass('closed').removeClass('opened'); 

  if (activePanel)
  {
    $(activePanel).find('b').addClass('opened').removeClass('closed'); 
  }
}
```

DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/0fHUqXpNn6#

NOTE: I noticed that you can actually click on the heading, which will cause the click callback, but not expand the accordion, you should probably set this event on a different control to avoid having the icon change when the actual accordion click doesn't get fired.

Comment: like so? I think you forgot something?